# JavaFX Show menu when mouse goes to the edge of the screen

Tags: javafx-8

I want to show (load) a menu when the mouse goes to the edge of the screen, and hide (remove) when the mouse goes away from the edge of the screen. I am trying to achieve what’s seen in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GsdaZWDcdY (forward 6 mins).

It works fine when Welcome.fxml screen has no children positioned at the edge of the screen. However, when the mouse goes over any of the children nodes, it stops reading the X,Y coordinates on the StackPane (base). I cannot use mouse transparent because some of the children nodes are buttons which need to use mouse events.

Appreciate any suggestions or resources for reference that can help me achieve this. Thanks.

---

public class Main extends Application {

```
    StackPane base = new StackPane();

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Welcome.fxml"));
    base.getChildren().add(root);
    Scene scene = new Scene(base);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    VBox menu = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Menu.fxml"));

    base.setOnMouseMoved((event) -> {
        if (event.getScreenX() < 40) {
            if (!base.getChildren().contains(menu)) {
                base.getChildren().add(menu);
                base.setAlignment(menu, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
            }
        } else {
            if (base.getChildren().contains(menu)) {
                base.getChildren().remove(menu);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried an event filter?

```
base.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, e -> {
    //Do your processing
});
```

Event filter should be the first to get the events.